# Append to an array for the new span element that is added via input text in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Am struggling hard to control an array object with list of span values using watcher in Angularjs.

It is partially working, when i input span elements, an array automatically gets created for each span and when I remove any span element -> respective row from the existing array gets deleted and all the other rows gets realigned correctly(without disturbing the value and name).

The problem is when I remove a span element and reenter it using my input text, it is not getting added to my array. So, after removing one span element, and enter any new element - these new values are not getting appended to my array.

**DemoCode** fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_panduga/d5ah88mh/1/)

What am I missing in my code?

How can I get reinserted spans to be appended to the existing array object without disturbing the values of leftover rows (name and values of array)?

Please note that values will get changed any time as per a chart.

This is the code am using:

```
<script>
    function rdCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.dataset_v1 = {};
        $scope.dataset_wc = {};
        $scope.$watch('dataset_wc', function (newVal) {
            //alert('columns changed :: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.dataset_wc, null, 2));
            $('#status').html(JSON.stringify($scope.dataset_wc));

        }, true);

        $(function () {
            $('#tags input').on('focusout', function () {
                var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.\#]/g, ''); // allowed characters
                if (txt) {
                    //alert(txt);
                    $(this).before('<span class="tag">' + txt.toLowerCase() + '</span>');
                    var div = $("#tags");
                    var spans = div.find("span");
                    spans.each(function (i, elem) { // loop over each spans
                        $scope.dataset_v1["d" + i] = { // add the key for each object results in "d0, d1..n"
                            id: i, // gives the id as "0,1,2.....n"
                            name: $(elem).text(), // push the text of the span in the loop
                            value: 3
                        }
                    });
                    $("#assign").click();
                }
                this.value = "";
            }).on('keyup', function (e) {
                // if: comma,enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
                if (/(188|13)/.test(e.which)) $(this).focusout();
                if ($('#tags span').length == 7) {
                    document.getElementById('inptags').style.display = 'none';
                }
            });

            $('#tags').on('click', '.tag', function () {
                var tagrm = this.innerHTML;
                sk1 = $scope.dataset_wc;
                removeparent(sk1);
                filter($scope.dataset_v1, tagrm, 0);
                $(this).remove();
                document.getElementById('inptags').style.display = 'block';
                $("#assign").click();
            });
        });

        $scope.assign = function () {
            $scope.dataset_wc = $scope.dataset_v1;
        };

        function filter(arr, m, i) {
            if (i < arr.length) {
                if (arr[i].name === m) {
                    arr.splice(i, 1);
                    arr.forEach(function (val, index) {
                        val.id = index
                    });
                    return arr
                } else {
                    return filter(arr, m, i + 1)
                }
            } else {
                return m + " not found in array"
            }
        }

        function removeparent(d1)
        {
            dataset = d1;
            d_sk = [];
            Object.keys(dataset).forEach(function (key) {
                // Get the value from the object
                var value = dataset[key].value;
                d_sk.push(dataset[key]);
            });
            $scope.dataset_v1 = d_sk;
        }
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at using ng-repeat?

Comment: yea, I used it for populating the lists.. Am not sure how can I use it for array object in my code... I just started learning Angularjs, (very new actually)

Comment: It looks like your trying to use angular as you would jquery but that really isn't how you should do it. If you use ng-repeat to define your spans then append the item to the array not the document. Angular then updates the document based on the array

Comment: And ps your initializing your variables to objects not arrays but once you delete an item it goes to an array

Comment: Are you essentially trying to make a table of span elements?

Comment: no, these input span elements are created via input text given by user (could be from 0 to 7).. These were independent spans. Each span -> creates new row in array object, and gets binded.. So, when I remove span -> row gets removed from existing array object

Comment: ill type up an example of what i mean

Comment: okay i added my answer that is the concept you can adjust it to meet your needs

Comment: Thanks a lot @Binvention .. I will give a try as suggested by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using angular i think you are going to want more on the html side of things particularly using ng-repeat and ng-click and ng-model first you would want to create your array which could simply be done in your code file or using ng-init. heres an example

```js
(function(){
  var app=angular.module('demoApp',[]);
  app.controller('demoApp',[function(){
    this.spans=[""];
    this.currentSpan='';
    this.addSpan=function(){
      this.spans.push(this.currentSpan);
   this.currentSpan='';
    };
    }]);
  })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demoApp'>
<div ng-controller='demoApp as demo'>
  <span ng-repeat='span in demo.spans track by $index' ng-click='demo.spans.splice($index,1)'>{{span}}</span><span>{{demo.currentSpan}}</span>
  <textarea ng-model='demo.currentSpan' placeholder='new text'></textarea>
  <button ng-click='demo.addSpan()' >add</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion!